# loop through array of replace innerhtml for both array values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace a certain word that is being generated on my site and after trying with different functions, this is what I found to be working:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML.replace("X","Y");
```

However, this class and word pops up several times, and I want to avoid writing...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML.replace("X","Y");
document.getElementsByClassName("label")[1].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("label")[1].innerHTML.replace("X","Y");
document.getElementsByClassName("label")[2].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("label")[2].innerHTML.replace("X","Y");
```

...like 20 times.

I've read about looping the array but I haven't found an example for when you basically have to define a number for that twice in the function and couldn't really derive a way to do it on my own.

Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```js
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("label"))
      .forEach(element => element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace("X","Y"));
```

```html
<div class="label">XYZ</div>
<div class="label">XYZ</div>
<div class="label">XYZ</div>
<div class="label">XYZ</div>
<div class="label">XYZ</div>
<div class="label">XYZ</div>
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more what should have been done differently with the initial code to work correctly?

Comment: @muras-cky I actually didn't copy your whole code, so it was actually my mistake, sorry!

Comment: I see, ok! Anyway, thank you again for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let labels = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
for(let lebel of labels){
    lebel.innerHTML = lebel.innerHTML.replace('X', 'Y');
   }
```